# ¿como consulto entre 5 tablas sql las cuales hay 2 con relaciones muchos a muchos?

Tags: sql

Hola amigos tengo un problema en mi consulta tengo 5 tablas

1)docente
2)materias
3)docente_materias
4)semestrees
5)semestres_materias

quiero hacer una consulta que me permita traer el docente y sus materias asignadas con su respectivo semestre

tengo esto pero me sale un error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error sugiere un posible fallo de escritura, con `maerias` en lugar de `materias`. No obstante, en el código de la pregunta no consigo visualizarlo. Falta la parte donde está el error antes mencionado, donde llamas a `maerias_docentes.docente_id` que debería ser `materias_docentes.docente_id`.

Comment: Hola NikeBoy 128, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines las imágenes, y adjuntes tu código y los mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos.

Comment: ```materias_docentes``` no forma parte del join, supongo que un error de escritura ya que debería ser ```materias_semestres```

Comment: Se agradece que en las preguntas pongas siempre el código y los mensajes de error **como texto**, no como imagen. Es más simple para ti (sólo copiar y pegar) y más útil para nosotros (el texto se puede leer mejor, y se puede usar para reproducir el problema si fuera necesario).